# How do I view KML network layers or WMS layers on mobile?

Tags: wms, google-earth, android, ios, kml-network-link

I want to view live layers (KML Network or WMS) on the phone. Google Earth application is very useful and advantageous for me and my team. But I guess Google Earth doesn't support live layers. Do I have a chance to do this through the Google Earth application? Or is there a any application like Google Earth (which is supports KML Network)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the [Arcgis Earth](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esri.earth.phone&hl=en&gl=US) application. This handles exactly what I want. It's free and supports WMS live layers.

Comment: Out of interest what do you mean by live WMS services?

Answer (score 0):

One option for you for WMS is to use the [OneGeology Portal](https://portal.onegeology.org/OnegeologyGlobal/) in your phone browser.

The portal comes with WMS already in it's catalogue of services, some of which are automatically loaded, and others can be added for use, selected by theme or geographically.  The portal is about sharing geological data, but you can add **any** WMS to it through the import functionality, you just need to add the WMS endpoint into the search (magnifying glass icon on a mobile).

The portal is free to use, and open source code.